# "The place where I go is nice" vs. "the place where I go to is nice"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I'm French and I'm wondering if the preposition *to* is needed in "The place where I go to is nice". I can see myself saying both "where I go to" and "where I go".

Comment: Thank you, that link you provided helped a lot to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

"The place where I go" implies that you go there routinely: "the place where I go to in the Dordogne each July is nice". Je vais au campagne l'ete.
"The place where I am going to" is future tense - J'irai au campagne cette annee.

Also, when we are at school we are told by our English teachers to avoid the word "nice" as a description.  Perhaps, if you wish, you could substitute "nice" for "beautiful, wonderful or super.

Comment: Ho yes, I see. But maybe I could also say:"The place where I go in the Dordogne each july is nice".